# relationship of electric circuit analysis to software engineering

Tags: circuit-analysis

i am starting my bachelors in software engineering so i want to know the use  of Electrical Circuit Analysis in softawre engineering? i have searched it on different websites but none could clear my concept.

Comment: I think you're not the only one that is unclear about the concept. What do you *think* should be the relation ship between something that is specifically designed to, well, analyze electrical circuits, and software engineering? Your question is **very** unclear.

Comment: actually i m cunfused in needs of it in the software engineering

Comment: There *isn't* any use of electrical circuit analysis in software engineering. The two are pretty much unrelated.

Comment: I mean why a software engineer has to be good in electronics  any other field like physics etc?

Comment: I'm an EE yet at University I learned to program in assembler. Did I use that knowledge ever since ? Nope. Was it useful for my general understanding of how computers work (which is expected of an EE) yes ! Don't question everything you need to learn now, what you get is **an education** which means you should also have a basic understanding of things which are not always directly related to your main subject. There are many questions on this site from programmers who want to **build some hardware** but have no clue about electronics. Having at least a basic understanding helps.

Comment: Given the number of basic questions asked by arduino etc. users here about interfacing the micro controller I would say that it would be very useful indeed.

Comment: Take a pure software engineer, whose system has false interrupts. What to do? Are the long wires to blame? Is the clock too fast for the metastable latches to resolve? Should the int-short (16 bits) become int-long(32 bits) so the Analog Digital Converter inputs get averaged to improve LSB bit dither? just a few examples

Answer (score 4):

A software engineer has zero need of electrical engineering concepts, short of how to turn on the coffee pot that fuels software writing.

However, an electrical engineer won't get very far without some smattering of software. For instance, when a spreadsheet doesn't quite cut it, or when the output of LTSpice is *almost* in the right format, but reformatting it is a bit too much work for a text editor. Or do you need to control that board you're building, write a soft front panel for it. Debug that embedded micro, expose it through a socket.

All software engineers need *domain* knowledge, so if the product is strongly related to electrical engineering, then they will need some knowledge of it.

Comment: +pi if I could.

Comment: There are some concepts in wayfinding algorithms which have equivalents in current distribution along a resistor network. So, understanding Kirchhoffs laws and see how electrical engineers solve such networks can help you understanding how such algorithms work. There is simply much more and much more practical advice how to do that for electrical networks than for wayfinding.